# Firebase upload raw data to bucket

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am creating an application in nodejs/typescript that uses Firebase  Functions and I basically need to upload a JSON object to a bucket. I am having issues because the JSON I am creating exists in memory, and is not an actual file - as the application is a serverless one.

I know firebase is just a wrapper for Google Cloud Functions and have looked for solutions everywhere however cannot seem to get this working. Is anyone able to give me any guidance or suggestions please?

If I cannot upload the in-memory file to a bucket, does anyone know if its possible to programatically export a database document as a json to a firestore bucket using firebase? (as I can easily just upload the json to a database document).

Below is one example of what I have tried. However the code is obviously invalid.

```
await storage()
  .bucket()
  .file('test.json') // A random string filename and not an existing file
  .createWriteStream()
  .write(JSON.stringify(SOME_VALID_JSON))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [save()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save) to write data in memory to a bucket.

```
await storage()
  .bucket()
  .file('test.json')
  .save(JSON.stringify(SOME_VALID_JSON))
```

Comment: Would you like to say in more detail what's happening that's different than what you expect?

Comment: You were correct - thanks very much! I had tried this however was catching errors incorrectly so my issues was elsewhere. Thanks for this - working now!